# Why can't I close the file

Tags: c

I have a problem when I close the file fc. 
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main()
{
   FILE* fc = fopen("template.txt","rt,ccs=UTF-8");
   wchar_t subStr[2300];  
   fread(subStr,sizeof(wchar_t),2300,fc);
   wchar_t* scrStr=new wchar_t[2300];
   wcscpy(scrStr,subStr);
   fclose(fc);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... what problem do you have?

Comment: (1). This is not valid C code. (2). How do you know you can't close the file? *have a problem* is unclear.

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen()`. It returns null if the file could not be opened.

Comment: Also why are you using `wchar_t` for UTF-8 (an 8-bit format)?

Comment: My problem: the program stops working when it reachs fclose(fc).
The file is opened
I use it to read Vietnamese characters

Comment: maybe buffer overrun at `wcscpy`

Answer (score 0):

The file was probably not opened correctly in the first place.  You must check that the 'handle' to the stream returned by `fopen` is not `NULL`.  The following code checks the file 'handle', with a few bits changed to make it 'reasonable' C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main()
{
    wchar_t* scrStr = NULL;  
    FILE* fc = fopen("template.txt","rt,ccs=UNICODE");
    // Check that the file was opened.
    if(NULL != fc)
    {
        wchar_t subStr[2301];  
        size_t wcharsRead = fread(subStr, sizeof wchar_t , 2300, fc);
        fclose(fc);
        // Check if anything was read.
        if(0 != wcharsRead)
        {
            // Terminate the string in the temporary buffer.
            subStr[wcharsRead] = `\0`;
            // Allocate a smaller string (use new, if you're in C++).
            if(scrStr = malloc(1 + sizeof wchar_t * wcharsRead), NULL != scrStr)
            {
                // Copy the useful bit into the new string.
                wcscpy(scrStr, subStr);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some error handling
        printf("Unable to open file.  Error code: %d\r\n",errno);
    }
    // Check if a string was read.
    if(NULL != scrStr)
    {
         // Do something with scrStr
         // Free the string once it's finished with (use delete if you're in C++).
         free(scrStr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```